# How to export Notes Document(email,task,etc.) from Lotus notes Client 8.5 into DXL File?

Tags: email, lotus-notes

I am using Lotus notes Client 8.5 and i want to export mail items into DXl file. can anyone tell me the steps to convert notes doxument into DXL file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Java agent to export a DXL file for all selected documents:

```java
import lotus.domino.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    @Override
    public void NotesMain() {

        try {
            Session session = getSession();
            AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
            DocumentCollection dc = agentContext.getUnprocessedDocuments();
            String filename = "c:/temp/exportDocs.dxl";
            Stream stream = session.createStream();
            if (stream.open(filename)) {
                stream.truncate();
                DxlExporter exporter = session.createDxlExporter();
                exporter.setRichTextOption(0);
                exporter.setMIMEOption(0);
                stream.writeText(exporter.exportDxl(dc));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Cannot open " + filename);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Leave default settings for new agent like "Target: All selected documents" as they are.

Open then a view, select documents and run the agent.

As an alternative you can create a LotusScript agent

```vb
Sub Initialize
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim filename As String
    Dim stream As NotesStream
    Dim exporter As NotesDXLExporter
    Set db = session.Currentdatabase
    set dc = db.UnprocessedDocuments
    filename = "c:/temp/exportDocs.dxl"
    set stream = session.createStream()
    If stream.Open(filename) Then
        Call stream.Truncate()
        set exporter = session.CreateDxlExporter()
        exporter.Richtextoption = 0
        exporter.MIMEOption = 0 
        Call stream.WriteText(exporter.Export(dc))
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: i am using lotus notes c++ api.how can i use this code in my code. can u give me lotus script code for dxl export?