# Extracting a url from a hotspot

Tags: lotus-notes

I've got a collection of url hotspots in a Notes document.  I'd like to extract the urls associated with the hotspots.  Any hints on how to approach this?

thanks
clem

Comment: It's probably a job for MIDAS (3rd party toolkit from Genii Software).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the DXL export features and then walking the resulting XML to find the URLs. Try it, and if you have issues, come back and ask questions about the specific piece of code.

Comment: Look how to create such a DXL file here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24409018/2065611

Comment: Thanks Knut for the tip.  I wrote an exporter, processed the xml file to extract the urls, then ran them through a url validator.  I can now keep the urls in my docs current.  Much appreciated!