# Change background color of richtexttablecell

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I like to change the backgroundcolor of a richtexttablecell, I try to solve the problem with lotusscript, but there isn't an method or attribute for this in lotus script.
looks like it is possible to solve this with c api.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `NotesDXLExporter` and `NotesDXLImporter`:

- export the document as DXL,
- replace table properties in DXL and
- import it back to document.

Make sure that you use `notesDXLExporter.RichTextOption=0`.

This is an example for a table with background colors in DXL format:

```xml
<item name='Body'>
    <richtext>
        <pardef id='1' />
        <par def='1' />
        <table widthtype='fixedleft' refwidth='2.1493in'>
            <tablecolumn width='1.0667in' />
            <tablecolumn width='1.0826in' />
            <tablerow>
                <tablecell bgcolor='blue'>
                    <pardef id='3' keepwithnext='true' keeptogether='true' />
                    <par def='3' />
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell bgcolor='red'>
                    <pardef id='4' keepwithnext='true' keeptogether='true' />
                    <par def='4' />
                </tablecell>
            </tablerow>
            <tablerow>
                <tablecell bgcolor='yellow'>
                    <par def='3' />
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <par def='4' />
                </tablecell>
            </tablerow>
        </table>
        <par def='1' />
    </richtext>
</item>
```

It should be easy to replace the bgcolor properties in DXL.

You can find a code snippet for DXL-export [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24409018/2065611).

Answer (score 1):

Background color does not appear to be exposed in the LS NotesRichTextStyle or NotesRightTextParagraphStyle classes. The alternate would to use HTML with MIME or the Midas Rich Text LSX from Genii Soft.