# Detect "Page Break" in RichText field with LotusScript

Tags: lotus-notes, rtf, lotusscript

How can I detect page breaks in an RTF field?

I need to do a process to replace page breaks with symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** do it with LotusScript Domino classes.

You **can** find all page breaks with the help of DXL export though:

1. export relevant documents https://stackoverflow.com/a/24409018/2065611
2. analyze RTFs in DXL - look für `<pardef`'s with `newpage='true'`

```xml
    <item name='Body'>
        <richtext>
        <pardef id='1'/>
        <par def='1'>a</par>
        <par def='1'>b</par>
        <pardef id='2' newpage='true'/>
        <par def='2'>c</par>
        <par def='1'>d</par>
        </richtext>
    </item>
```

The harder job will be to replace all occurrences:

1. replace the content in document's DXL
2. import document's DXL into a temporary document
3. replace RTFs in original Notes document with the modified RTFs from temporary document

Comment: I have the DXL exported and I have replaced <pardef id = '2' newpage = 'true' /> with my symbol. But I've never worked with DXL, Can you help me with the import?

Comment: Look at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_IMPORT_METHOD_IMPORTER.html and the examples provided there.